# load list depend on category in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

trying to make a small application
there is the category ( places, coffee Shops, Clubs)

how to load the list of respective category in the knockout.

how to load the list of tags (only once) and which is clickable and load the tag list when click

here is my code
**JS**

```
var points = [
    {
        tag: "places",
        name: "Dubai Marina",
    }, {
        tag: "places",
        name: "Burj Khalifa",
    }, {
        tag: "Coffee",
        name: "StarBucks",
    }, {
        tag: "Coffee",
        name: "Costa",
    }, {
        tag: "Club",
        name: "Beach Club",
    }, {
        tag: "Club",
        name: "Cheers Club",
    }
];

var View = function (data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.pointsList = ko.observableArray([]);

    points.forEach(function (e) {
        self.pointsList.push(new View(e));
        console.log(e)
    });

    self.activeTag = function (a) {
        console.log(a);
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

** HTML**

```
<ul class="list-inline" data-bind="foreach:points">
        <li data-bind="text:tag, click: activeTag"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul data-bind="foreach:points">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    </ul>
```

Or is there any better solution?

Comment: Please explain your problem a little better, I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish and what the problem exactly is. Maybe providing a JSFiddle might also help us understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so there is really nice website here http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html that has all the functions you need.

I used the link and used the following
1. flatten the array (just get the names)
2. getting just the unique values in the array (unique names)
3. did a foreach on the unique names. then on click. I changed my search criteria for a filtered array.  you can run the whole thing below. just click run snippet.

```js
function point(tag, name) {
  var self = this;
  this.tag = ko.observable(tag);
  this.name = ko.observable(name)
}

function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.points = ko.observableArray('');
  this.selectedPoint = ko.observable('');

  this.setSelected = function(item) {
    self.selectedPoint(item);
  }

  this.justtags = ko.computed(function() {
    var tags = ko.utils.arrayMap(this.points(), function(item) {
      return item.tag();
    });
    return tags.sort();
  }, this);

  this.uniquetags = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(self.justtags()).sort();
  }, this);

  this.filteredNames = ko.computed(function() {
    var filter = self.selectedPoint()
    if (!filter) {
    } else {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.points(), function(item) {
        if (item.tag() === filter) {
          return item
        };
      });
    }
  }, this);

}

var data = [{
  tag: "places",
  name: "Dubai Marina",
}, {
  tag: "places",
  name: "Burj Khalifa",
}, {
  tag: "Coffee",
  name: "StarBucks",
}, {
  tag: "Coffee",
  name: "Costa",
}, {
  tag: "Club",
  name: "Beach Club",
}, {
  tag: "Club",
  name: "Cheers Club",
}];

var vm = new viewModel();
$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    vm.points.push(new point(item.tag, item.name));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-inline" data-bind="foreach:uniquetags">
  <li data-bind="text:$data, click: $parent.setSelected"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-inline" data-bind="foreach:filteredNames">
  <li data-bind="text:name"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi, Bryan, quick question. I added google map with a marker of the locations(lat & lng) from the data [].  for example, When clicking on 'Places' it will show the only related marker. 
`
this.currentPoint = function(e){
        this.location(e.location);
        console.log(this.location(e.location));
    }` and passing  marker position 'position: vm.currentPoint.location,' but its not working

Answer (score 0):

This is the ideal problem to get familiar with `ko.pureComputed` properties!

Your viewmodel has two *main* properties:

- An array of `Point`s
- A selected "tag"

All other properties can be computed by combining these two. Here's how:

- We create a computed object that orders our Points by their tag property.

  ```
  { "Club": [ Point, ... ] }
  ```
- We create a computed array that takes only the selected tag from this object
- We create a computed array that takes all keys of the object to represent the available tags

I've moved some code around and chose a `<select>` box as a quick UI solution.

```js
var Point = function (name, tag) {
  this.name = ko.observable(name);
  this.tag = ko.observable(tag);
};

Point.fromData = function(data) {
  return new Point(data.name, data.tag);
}

var ViewModel = function () {
  // This is a list of Point viewmodels, only used inside the vm
  var pointsList = ko.observableArray(
    getPoints().map(Point.fromData)
  );
  
  // This is the tag (string) that is selected, or null if there's
  // no selection
  this.activeTag = ko.observable(null);

  // This is an object that orders your points by their tag name in
  // a plain object. I.e.: { 'tagname': [Point] }
  var pointsMap = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return pointsList().reduce(function(map, point) {
      var tag = point.tag();
      map[tag] = map[tag] || [];
      map[tag].push(point);
      return map;
    }, {});
  }, this);
  
  // All the keys in our object represent all available tags
  this.allTags = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return Object.keys(pointsMap()).sort();
  }, this);
  
  // This is a computed list of Points. It combines the
  // selected tag and takes corresponding Point array from our map
  this.activePoints = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var tag = this.activeTag();
    
    return tag 
      ? pointsMap()[tag]
      : pointsList();
  }, this);
  
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

function getPoints() {
  return [{tag:"places",name:"Dubai Marina"},{tag:"places",name:"Burj Khalifa"},{tag:"Coffee",name:"StarBucks"},{tag:"Coffee",name:"Costa"},{tag:"Club",name:"Beach Club"},{tag:"Club",name:"Cheers Club"}];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: allTags, value: activeTag, optionsCaption: 'no filter'"></select>
<ul data-bind="foreach: activePoints">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```